# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE on device

Tags: android, performance

I run my app from Android Studio (clicking the green right-pointing arrow in Android Studio) to a device (Samsung SM-T530NU, rooted)
Then I stop it and uninstall it. 
Then I run it again 
I see this in logcat:

*Executing tasks: [:myapp:assembleDebug]

Gradle build finished in 2s 525ms

Session 'myapp': running

Session 'myapp': error*

So the app does not run.
Then I do a rebuild. Then click run and I see this:
*Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE.

Do you want to remove the application data?*

The device has plenty of storage (about 7 of 16gb used) and about 2/3 of memory is used, with myapp using about 90mb of memory.

I've tried various measures suggest here,
[Android: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133199/android-installation-error-install-failed-insufficient-storage)
but nothing helps.

What is the problem?

Comment: Check your device storage, its most likley almost full.. clear some data and try running the app again

Comment: As originally stated, the device has plenty of storage (about 7 of 16gb used), so I don't see how uninstalling some applications is going to help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because this belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall one or two applications from you device

Comment: As originally stated, the device has plenty of storage (about 7 of 16gb used), so I don't see how uninstalling some applications is going to help.

Comment: 7 of 16 gb internal or external ?

Comment: This device does not have an SD card